# jQuery Adding and Removing Images from a Div Container

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery and really need help trying to figure this one out. I need a script that will:

1. Add images from an image container to a different parent div container.
2. Determine whether or not the image has been added to the div already
3. Limit the amount of images that can be added to the new parent div
4. Remove an image from the new parent div onclick
5. Make the image available in its original container again for addition.

** If we could send the div image values (src or title) in a jquery $.post afterward that would be icing on the cake.

I seem to have 1,3 and 4 working.  However 2 and 5 are driving me nuts.  Maybe someone has this running somewhere??

Here's what I have already (in case it helps. i feel like i am way off.)

http://jsfiddle.net/pm284/LnqBt/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img.selectImage').click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        var addimg = '<img class="added" src="' + src + '" title="' + title + '" height="50" width="50" />';    
        //first lets count the elements within the div.
        var number = $('#imgBox img').length;
        var imgMax = '5';
        if(number == imgMax){
            alert('You are at the max amout of images / 5');
        }//<!-end if tag

        //if the count is less than five we can add an image.   
        else {  
            $(this).css('border','1px solid #000');
            $('#addText').hide();   
            $('#imgBox').append(addimg);

            //we need to be able to remove the image also. 
            $('#imgBox img').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).remove();
            });

        }//<!-end else tag

    });
});
```

Comment: What should happen for #2? It would be easy to check the src attribute, but what will you do with that information? For #5, did you plan on removing the images from the original container on click? Currently there's no need to put them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by adding condition checking the src of the clicked image, you can see if you already added it. The condition look like this:

```
if(!$('#imgBox').find('[src="'+src+'"]').length)
```

Then, for removing the border, I saved the clicked element and reused it in the other click function. The final code look like this :

```
if(!$('#imgBox').find('[src="'+src+'"]').length){
    var theImage = $(this);
    $(this).css('border','1px solid #000');
    $('#addText').hide();   
    $('#imgBox').append(addimg);

    //we need to be able to remove the image also. 
    $('#imgBox img').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        theImage.css('border', 'none')
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LnqBt/5/

Comment: I call that hitting the nail on the head.  Thanks a million!